# How to return an object from method to calculate with it?

Tags: java

I want to do this: `sum += castObjectToNumber(value)` and `castObjectToNumber` should look somehow like this:

```
private Number castObjectToNumber(Object value) {
    if(value instanceof Integer) {
        return (int)value;
    } else if(value instanceof Float) {
        return (float) value;
    } else if(value instanceof Double) {
        return (double) value;
    } else if(value instanceof Long) {
        return (long) value;
    } else if(value instanceof Byte) {
        return (byte) value;
    } else if(value instanceof Short) {
        return (short) value;
    }
}
```

I can't change that I get a value of type Object and I want this to be a general purpose solution. My problem here is that if I return a Number object, as this is the only thing all these types have in common, I can't use the `+=` operator with it. So how do I do this in Java? I think I do choose a wrong return type and thus it won't work but I'm not sure what is the right one.

Comment: Can you tell us why you're trying to accomplish this?  Autoboxing will do most of what you want but you may need to cast.  The += operator will only work with primitives.

Comment: Autoboxing seem to not detect that it is a number like a double and not a complex object. Thus I think I have to do this by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sum variable has a predetermined type, most likely double, because double is the "biggest" of those types. Therefore, you can safely convert all number types to double. This example assumes that your object can be casted to Number.

```
Number number = (Number) obj;
sum += number.doubleValue();
```

Comment: This looks like the best way to achieve what I wanted. I should have checked more precisely what Number class provides and thought of double as biggest type rather than using smallest type possible.

Answer (score 0):

since there's no direct way to override arithmetic operators in java - is suggest you'll just add 2 methods to your 'Number' class:
add(Number n), sub(Number n) to perform the arithmetic operations you need

Comment: [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) is the abstract class from which Integer, Double, etc. are derived.